nestjs commander option choices not working
In the view that the nestjs commander is simply lacking a sensible documentation, I'm wasting time trying to figure out why this does not work:
  @Option({
    flags: '-m, --merchant [merchant]',
    required: true,
    description: 'merchant name',
    choices: ['MyMerchant'],
  })
  merchant(val: string) {
    return val;
  }

I take it, the only value possible should be MyMerchant, however the app keeps accepting all values...What needs to be done to make it work?
I'm starting regretting using this module instead of using the actual commander.
